# django rest_framework using stored procedure

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How can I use my stored procedure in django rest framework,

let's say I have an ***add_item*** that insert product name and date_acquired

```
select add_item(p_name,p_date_acquired)
```

We have models.py

```
# using RAW models
Class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_acquired = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What should I put in my serializer.py

Something like this perhaps? what about my views

```
class ProductSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields = ['name',
              'date_acquired'
```

Please Help thank you

Edit: I try to create

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def insert(request):
    serialize = ProductSerialize(data=request.data)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select add_item('"+serialize +"')")
```

but it's not working obviously

Comment: so you want to create view for this serializer?

Comment: yes I want to create a view not using django's ORM but django raw SQL for my stored procedure, sorry if my english is not good

Comment: did u mean that you want an additional field in serializer that is the result of a function?

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand your question, the thing is I created a complex stored procedure and I want to know how can I use it to create an API

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIZup2IaCkk check 13:20, in the video his using an stored procedure to display a table which sometimes an django ORM cannot handle or too complex

Comment: but this is for displaying something, how about inserting a data

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work.  Are you hitting your insert endpoint correctly?